# TextChanged event firing although I use bool to disable that

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to to reset all field on frame, but while do that i need to `disable textchanged event`

For this i try to use bool variable. like this:

First method that wold enable me to find all `TextBox` child on frame.

```
bool skipChange = false; 

public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{            
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                 yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This enables me to find all children of some type and reset it.

I reset it  like :

```
public void resetForm() {
    foreach (TextBox tb in FindVisualChildren<TextBox>(sPanelMain))
    {
        tb.Text = "";                
    }
 }
```

For finally i need to call resetForm method and disable textchnged to fire.

```
private void btnAddForm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    skipChange = true;
    resetForm();
    skipChange = false;
}


 private void PDText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     if (skipChange) { return; }
     ....
 }
```

On this way I trying to exit from TextChanged method if `skipChange` is true.

But in TextChanged method skipChange is always false,although I set it on true before calling.

Thanx

Comment: To investigate the problem, you could set breakpoints (or trace debug info).. at beginning of `PDText_TextChanged` method and on `skipChange = false;` instruction, then look at call stack inside `PDText_TextChanged` to check whether it gets called synchronously/immediately or not.

Comment: @Rubidium37 thanx for answer, you give me right guidance.From some reason I did not notice that,but now i see that `first` is calling `skipChange = false;` and thant `textchanged` from some reason. I wold try to find now ,when i know that.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
skipChange = true;
resetForm();

//Your final assignment is false, try to run it by just assigning it to true
```

This line:

```
skipChange = false;
```

Comment: Thanx , but that skipChange is always true after method call.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that works, but you could try removing and reattaching the event handler like so:

```
public void resetForm() {
    foreach (TextBox tb in FindVisualChildren<TextBox>(sPanelMain))
    {
        tb.TextChanged -= PDText_TextChanged;
        tb.Text = "";    
        tb.TextChanged += PDText_TextChanged;            
    }
 }
```

Comment: thanx for answer. Before this i use something similar. and it work. But on that way i wold write this for every textbox(i cannot use foreach) But if i not find problem, than i wold use this. :)

Answer (score 0):

On the end i figure it. Whit right direction from @Rubidium 37 and suggestion from @Florian Gl and @ pammy Bhat I change my code , and now work.

From `btnAddForm` method i remove `skipChange = true;` and `skipChange = false;`

```
private void btnAddForm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    resetForm();
}
```

In `resetForm` methof I set `skipChange` to true in foreach loop, that way with every textbox control I setting  it on true.

```
public void resetForm() {
    foreach (TextBox tb in FindVisualChildren<TextBox>(sPanelMain))
    {
        skipChange = true;
        tb.Text = "";                
    }
}
```

And on the and I change

```
if (skipChange) { return; }
```

to:

```
if (skipChange) { skipChange=false; return; }
```

This work greate. Thanx to all for suggestions.